# Convert ISO 8601 to a different ISO 8601 format using MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs, iso8601

Is there a way for a format like this:

> 2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1000
>   or
>   2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1100

To be converted like this

> 2003-09-25T14:00:00.000Z

Without using manual and only using MomentJS. I also want to know what +1000 or +1100 means.

Comment: +1000 == Plus 10:00 hours GMT, e.g. Melbourne, Australia

Comment: So what happens when this is for instance +8000 say (Singapore, Kuala Lumpur), is it still equals to 2003-09-25T14:00:00.000Z?

Comment: No, the `Z` stands for UTC, have a look at [timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) info page and at momentjs doc.

Comment: In particular `2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1000` and `2003-09-25T14:00:00.000Z` aren't the same time : `2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1000` and `2003-09-25T04:00:00.000Z` are (notice the 04 hours instead of 14).

Comment: Z stands for Zulu, which is a military synonym for UTC time. It just means that the time is in the format of 24-hours and the time represented is local time with the offset from GMT time. If it was true UTC, there would be no offset and the time would directly reflect GMT.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Not sure if I understood you correctly, but from wikipedia article on ISO 8601: `If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space`. I'm used to the absence of timezone specification meaning localtime and the Z meaning UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to get the offset hours and add them back to the time.

```js
var timeStrings = [
  '2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1000',
  '2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1100'
];

console.log(timeStrings.map(ts => {
  var m = moment(ts);
  m.add(m._tzm, 'minutes'); // Add total minute offset
  return m.toISOString();
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

Alternative approach that does not modify the moment objects when displayed.

```js
var timeStrings = [
  '2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1000',
  '2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1100'
];
var moments = timeStrings.map(ts => moment(ts));

// The moments are not modified when displayed...
console.log(moments.map(momentDateAsUtc));

function momentDateAsUtc(m) {
  var clone = m.clone();
  clone.add(m._tzm, 'minutes'); // Add total minute offset
  return clone.toISOString();
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But then it's not the same time anymore. Which indeed is what OP asked for, but may not be what he actually needs.

Comment: There is no way to format it as true UTC without modifying the object's time. At least with vanilla Moment. Maybe there is a library that clones and adds the current date when formatting.

Comment: I'm really confused by your comments, I'm wondering if I'm totally missing something. Care to check my answer?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl do not use [Internal Properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) like `_tzm`, use [`utcOffset`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) instead.

Comment: I actually liked your answer, it worked for me. Thanks! Maybe I can do a simple edit to avoid using internal properties..

Comment: @VincenzoC If I use `utcOffset()` I get a different response. That is why I used the internal one. The call to `moment.utcOffset()` will return MY local offset.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to display the times in UTC, there actually isn't anything to do because momentjs already handle times in UTC internally, converting your offset dates to UTC as it parses them :

```js
var moments = [
  moment('2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1000'), // 2PM in Srednekolymsk, Russia
  moment('2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1100')  // 2PM in Sydney, Australia
]; // Note that they are NOT the same time, nor are they the same as 14:00:00Z
console.log(moments);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```